# Running Application as Local Admin without needing to manually input password

Tags: vbscript, passwords, admin

Working on trying to script an install of the Flash Standalone Installer, amongst other things, for all of our 400-600 or so users. I'm trying the "runas /user:admin" as there is a local admin account on all PCs for the purposes of installing software.

In an attempt to keep the password out of the users hands, I've tried encrypted password programs such as LSRunAsE but that has had very very limited success with this. At this point, I am hoping to just create a .vbs with the necessary runas command for cmd to be able to run this and just password protect the file and move on but I don't see a way to even write the runas command with the password intact.

Has anyone else tried to do something similar with any luck? Any programs I could try? I realize that this is something that has pretty much been eliminated with software deployment software, but I'm working on getting something approved for that, but just need to get this working in the meantime.

Comment: Talk to your network administrator. They can install programs. Programmers can't as you may be a virus.

Comment: Yeah. Network admin's answer is for the user to contact us every time they have to install or update something and have us do it remotely. Trying to make it so users can just do it themselves and free the rest of us up.

Comment: You can't bypass passwords. Group Policy doesn't need passwords from the user (because an admin configured it). Do things the Windows way - MS thought long and hard about these issues.

Comment: Thought about using `psexec.exe` from the SysInternals PsTools? Allows you execute process remotely with a System level access...very useful on closed networks for deploying scripts etc.